# Кодирование Хэмминга

Tags: c#, массивы, перебор

Срочно нужна помощь. Алгоритм кодирования (он несложный) доступен по ссылкам:

- [Вычисление](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~downeyt/cop3402/hamming.html)
- [Статья на Хабре с алгоритмом](https://habr.com/ru/post/140611/)

Мне необходимо реализовать цикл/метод/что угодно, который будет вычислять контрольный бит.

Вычисление бита выглядит примерно так: если, к примеру, мы вычисляем третий контрольный бит, его порядковый номер равен (2^3 - 1) (т.к. массив начинается с нуля), а равен бит сумме (по модулю 2) 2^3 битов начиная с члена (2^3 - 1) через 2^3 бит (в статье на Хабре всё подробно описано).
Например, длина сообщения равна 8, первый бит вычисляется ([0] + [2] + [4] + [6] + [8] + [10]) % 2 (закодированное сообщение становится длиннее на Log2(длина исх. сообщения).

Прошу помочь примерным алгоритмом / псевдокодом / кодом на c#.

Мне удалось пока только реализовать заполнение контрольных битов нулями перед их вычислением.

Пример:
Ввод: 10011010
Вывод: 011100101010
При условии корректной работы программы, но на данный момент работает следующим образом:
Ввод: 10011010
Вывод: 0 0 1 7 0 0 1 56 1 0 1 0

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Введите сообщение: ");
    string inMessage = Console.ReadLine();
    byte[] codedMessage = new byte[(int)(inMessage.Length + Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(inMessage.Length, 2)) + 1)];
    bool wasCodeBit;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < codedMessage.Length; i++)
    {
        wasCodeBit = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(inMessage.Length, 2)) + 1; j++)
        {
            if (i == Math.Pow(2, j) - 1)
            {
                codedMessage[i] = 0;
                wasCodeBit = true;
            }
        }
        if (!wasCodeBit)
        {
            codedMessage[i] = byte.Parse(inMessage[count].ToString());
            count++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(inMessage.Length, 2)); i++) //сложение необходимых битов в контрольный
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < codedMessage.Length; j++)
        {
            if ((j - i + 1) / i % 2 == 0)
                codedMessage[(int)Math.Pow(2, i) - 1] += codedMessage[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(inMessage.Length, 2)); i++) //окончание сложения по модулю 2
        codedMessage[(int)Math.Pow(2, i) - 1] %= 2;
    foreach (int x in codedMessage)
        Console.Write($"{x} ");
}
```

Comment: ну вы же даже не пытались самостоятельно написать код, зачем кому-то пытаться делать это за вас?

Comment: Я полторы недели уже пытаюсь

Comment: добавьте ваши попытки, ваш код в вопрос. Опишите, что в нем работает не так, как вы ожидаете.

Comment: Конечно, минуту

Comment: В итоге работает только заполнение контрольных битов нулями, остальное я не могу реализовать, код составлен на основе подсказок со стаковерфлоу

Comment: какую вы выбрали длину информационного слова?

Comment: Здесь она динамическая, вычисляется по формуле (длина_исходного_сообщения) + Log2(длина_исходного сообщения) с округлением в большую сторону

Comment: то есть получается, что вы кодируете все сообщение одним блоком, верно?

Comment: + добавьте примеры данных на входе и выходе

Comment: Да, верно, всё одним блоком, примеры добавил

Comment: у вас вывод должен быть бинарным, откуда там появились числа 7 и 56?

Comment: Немного подправил, вывод бинарный, но код считает до сих пор неверно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Накатал примерный алгоритм. По крайней мере на ваших данных отрабатывает.

```
void Encode()
{   
    var messageArray = new BitArray(new byte[] { (byte)0b01011001});

    int messageInd = 0;
    int retInd = 0;
    int controlIndex = 1;

    var retArray = new BitArray(messageArray.Length + 1 + (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log2(messageArray.Length)));   

    while (messageInd < messageArray.Length)
    {
        if (retInd + 1 == controlIndex)
        {           
            retInd++;
            controlIndex = controlIndex * 2;
            continue;
        }

        retArray.Set(retInd, messageArray.Get(messageInd));

        messageInd++;
        retInd++;
    }

    retInd = 0;
    controlIndex = 1 << (int)Math.Log2(retArray.Length);

    while (controlIndex > 0)
    {
        int c = controlIndex - 1;
        int counter = 0;

        while (c < retArray.Length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < controlIndex && c < retArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (retArray.Get(c))
                    counter++;
                c++;
            }
            c += controlIndex;
        }

        if (counter % 2 != 0) retArray.Set(controlIndex - 1, true);
        controlIndex = controlIndex / 2;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("input");
    for (int i = 0; i < messageArray.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write($"{(messageArray.Get(i) ? 1 : 0)}   ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("output");
    for (int i = 0; i < retArray.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write($"{(retArray.Get(i) ? 1 : 0)}   ");
    }
}
```

Вывод

```
input
1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   
output
0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
```

Comment: Как записывать значения в эту коллекцию BitArray?

Comment: Туда можно отправить набор байт. Сама коллекция, по сути, это массив битов

Comment: Это я нагуглил, меня интересует, каким образом задать последовательность байт? Меня удивило выражение "0b01011001"

Comment: Я попробовал записать выражение длиной 16 бит, но выкинуло ошибку, не затруднит на словах объяснить алгоритм, чтобы я адаптировал его под безразмерную строку?

Comment: Я исправил, очень благодарен, вы меня спасли

Comment: пожалуйста. Рад, что вы справились :)